# How does 802.11 MAC unfairness impact TCP performance?

Tags: networking, tcp, wifi

One of the major factors that affect TCP performance in 802.11 ad hoc networks is the unfairness in the MAC. Could someone please illustrate for me what this "unfairness" means?

Answer (score 2):

In ad hoc networks, you usually are trying to do multihop routing.  802.11 CSMA/CA can manifest the "exposed terminal problem" in these situations.  Consider a linear topology

```
    ... A <---> T <---> B ...
```

A and B are not in CSMA range.  Suppose T is already transmitting a data stream to A. Now suppose a TCP stream starts getting routed through B.  Because B CSMAs with A, it will essentially be locked out of the channel.  The TCP connection being routed through B will eventually timeout.

Another possibility is the "hidden terminal problem".  Consider the topology

```
     A ---> X <--- B
```

A and B cannot CSMA.  Suppose A and B each try to send a TCP stream to X.  Because they cannot CSMA with each other, both win their respective channel contention rounds and transmit, only to have their frames collide at X.  This can be solved to some extent with RTS/CTS.  But in general, the reason for poor TCP performance in wireless environments has to do with the fact that TCP uses a dropped packet as a congestion signal, i.e., a TCP source will cut its window and there by drop its throughput.  In wireless networks, dropped packets can be due to any number of transient things (e.g., collision, interference).  A TCP source misinterprets these packet drops as a congestion signal and will throttle its send rate and underutilize the channel.

Another problem that can arise is due to the "capture effect".  Again, consider

```
    A ----> X <-------------B
```

Both A and B are in range of X, but B is farther away and thus has a lower received signal strength at X.  Again, A and B cannot CSMA.  In this case, X may "capture" the stronger transmitter A, i.e., its radio will decode A's frames but consider B's as noise (even though in the absence of A, X would go right ahead and decode B's frames).  This sets up an unfair advantage for A if both are trying to route a TCP stream through X.

802.11's DCF also favors the last winner of the channel contention round.  As a result, this gives a slight advantage to long-lived, bulk TCP transfers.

Note that all these problems affect all transport protocols, not just TCP.  It's just that the way TCP is designed makes it react particularly poorly to these scenarios.